# Нет перевода для "about us"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

В первой строке нижнего колонтитула сайта SO RU и на Мета тоже, не переведён один пункт:

**about us** тур справка дневник чат ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо за замечание! Слетела строка. Все нужные изменения уже были внесены, но не обновлена база строк. Сделал обновление. После ближайшего разворачивания сборки новые строки станут доступны.